# Function for a hexagonal 2-dimensional grid

Tags: trigonometry

I can make a "square" $2$D sine wave pattern with the function $f(x,y) = \cos(x) + \cos(y)$:

[image: square grid]

What is the function to make a hexagonal pattern of the same kind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about 
$$
f(x,y) = \cos x + \cos(\tfrac12 x +\tfrac{\sqrt 3}2y)+\cos(\tfrac12 x -\tfrac{\sqrt 3}2y)?
$$
See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos(x)+%2B+cos(x%2F2+%2B+ySqrt%5B3%5D%2F2)+%2B+cos(x%2F2+-+y+Sqrt%5B3%5D%2F2)) for a plot:

[image]

The idea is that $\cos(ax+by)$ will be large when $ax+by\approx 2\pi k$, and small when $ax+by\approx 2\pi k+\frac12$. This means there are periodic stripes of slope $\frac{-a}b$. In my example, the slopes of the stripes of the three summands are $\infty$ (i.e. vertical) and $\pm \frac1{\sqrt3}$, which correspond to making an angle of $\pm 30^\circ$ with the $x$ axis.

A better way of writing the same function is
$$
f(x,y) = \cos x + \cos(-\tfrac12 x +\tfrac{\sqrt 3}2y)+\cos(-\tfrac12 x -\tfrac{\sqrt 3}2y)
$$
and then noting that the vectors $(1,0),(-\tfrac12, \tfrac{\sqrt 3}2),(-\tfrac12, -\tfrac{\sqrt 3}2)$ are three unit vectors which meet at $120^\circ$ angles at the origin.

Comment: Thanks! It would be really helpful if you could provide some explanation for how this works-- for instance, why is there a standalone $cos(x)$ term but not a corresponding one for $y$?

Comment: Replacing all the cosines with sines makes the function symmetric in positive and negative values (right now you have only positive peaks and no negative troughs).

Comment: @SeanMackesey See edit, I mostly guessed based on your answer so my explanation is spotty.